# Diode selection

Tags: dc, diodes

I have a very simple circuit but have no idea on what or how to chose a diode for it.

It is for a uni project and we are being marked on our justification for choosing the diodes.

Is there such thing as a normal diode? That simply blocks current in one direction and is not designed for anything else? There are so many different types I don't know where to start.

I need to place diodes where I have indicated on the schematic. Can anyone suggest any specific models? I've figure the highest forward current will be around 25A, while voltage is around 100V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSYGS7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This question seems like a modification to your previous [question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/149429/choosing-a-correct-diode).

Comment: Yes it is but I never got an answer on what type of diodes to use.

Comment: *"we are being marked on our justification for choosing the diodes"* by *we*, do you mean *you* or *us*?

Comment: "Yes it is but I never got an answer on what type of diodes to use" --actually you did, Nedd gave you all the required information you need to work it out yourself.  In any case you can't just ask the same question again, you have to wait for more answers to your original question.

Comment: Nedd was very helpful yes, and did offer a lot of information. However I wasn't able to find a diode from the information he supplied, maybe because of my very limited knowledge on them. I am looking for a diode that serves the sole purpose of directing current in one direction only. I have researched Zener diodes, however "These are normally used only if you want a fixed voltage at some point in the circuit" and don't seem suitable. Rectifiers seem like they are meant for converting AC to DC, signal diodes are not rated for the current in my circuit. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: When you say you want a diode to pass current in one direction only, you are exactly describing *rectification*. This also happens to be useful for converting a.c. to dc, but the basic meaning is just letting current pass in only one direction.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning.

First let me tell you that I adjusted the answer 3) of your original question on this circuit.  There was some confusion related to whether all the 3 sections were to be taken together or each taken separately.  See the old question for edits.

In the new circuit above I would think that D2 should be moved one branch to the left, but maybe you received some other feedback on this.  (for example are "b" and "a" being shown only as a thevenin equivalent form?  I would think that "b" actually represents a battery that could possibly source up to 13A if needed.)

Next, I hope you know that the diode types you show in the latest circuit are definitely not appropriate.  But maybe you just used these as patterns to fill the diagram for now. The 1N4148 parts are relatively low current and low voltage diodes.  (You can look these up to get a feel for diode selection methods.)

Some more ideas:

With the D1 diode included below voltage "d" how is any current getting into that branch?  You are showing a current "i2-i3" directed into there.

If the 13A source is taken as a thevenin equivalent it could be modeled as a voltage supply of less then 100 volts, assuming all the parallel resistors, (but the actual voltage also depends on the placement of a possible third diode to the left of R1.  (See explanation now in the old answers.)

So did you look up a diode capable of 100v and 25A?  I'm not sure where the 25A came from though, unless you really need to take the 13A source 100% literal.  In that case a 25A would work but seems a bit excessive.  With one known voltage already at 80v the 100v parameter is a good start. You might even consider stepping up to a 200v diode to have a better safety margin.

New edit:
Here is a typical diode selection page from Digikey.....
http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/diodes-rectifiers-single/1376383?k=diode

Comment: Thanks Nedd. I have located a rectifier that looks sufficient (link below). The circuit I supplied actually changes. It is based off a solar panel, wind generator and hydro generator, where each source is not always supplying, which is why it is wired the way it is. The optimised circuit is a lot different, with the voltage sources in series etc. I am having trouble though adding the specs from the diode into Circuit Lab however as they seem to be labelled differently http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MUR2510R/1242-1016-ND/3594442